Trying to route /api/data using Axios but getting 404 error
I have tried to manually route myself to API/data and it also gives me the same error. Same on Postman or CURL -X.
I am running the backend on 5000 port and I have tried using Postman at 5000 and Curl at the same endpoint too. Still it gives error 404
Routes.py
from flask import jsonify
from . import create_app, db
from .models import Insight

app = create_app()

@app.route('/api/data', methods=['GET'])
def get_data():
    data = Insight.query.all()
    result = [
        {
            'end_year': d.end_year,
            'intensity': d.intensity,
            'sector': d.sector,
            'topic': d.topic,
            'insight': d.insight,
            'url': d.url,
            'region': d.region,
            'start_year': d.start_year,
            'impact': d.impact,
            'added': d.added,
            'published': d.published,
            'country': d.country,
            'relevance': d.relevance,
            'pestle': d.pestle,
            'source': d.source,
            'title': d.title,
            'likelihood': d.likelihood
        } for d in data
    ]
    return jsonify(result)

This is a fronted/frontend/src/services directory.
api.js
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000/api',
});

export const getInsights = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await api.get('/data'); 
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching insights:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

I am expecting a JSON output from my database.

Do you see the intended json when you navigate http://localhost:5000/api/data on your browser?

you could check in DevTools if it loads correct URL. Maybe it loads http://localhost:5000/data

maybe better create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run.
